# ¿Cómo recorrer un Enum filtrando por tipo y por numero de índice?

Tags: c#, enum

Quería saber cual es la forma de recorrer y filtrar un `enum` por el tipo que tengo y que llame a diferente método dependiendo de un parámetro de par o impar para recoger únicamente los valores pares o impares según la posición de los `enum`.

Ejemplo Enum:

```
 public enum EstadoVisita
    {
        NoVisitado,
        Entregado,
        Cobrado,
        NoCobrado,
        EntregadoMod,
        Fallado
    }
```

Tengo mi método `RecorrerEstado()`:

```
public void RecorrerEstado() 
{
    foreach (EstadoVisita item in EstadoVisita) 
    {
        RealizarContexto(item);
    }
}
```

¿Como puedo hacer para pasarle un parámetro para los pares/impares y que me filtre mejor el tipo?

Comment: ¿Pares/impares por valor del enumerado o por posición en la declaración del enumerado?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster par/impar por posicion del enumerado

Comment: Por un lado, no está claro lo que quieres encontrar, lo mejor, sería que pongas un ejemplo de salida.. Por otro lado, te recomiendo que reformules un poco el cuerpo de la pregunta, ya que se basa en opiniones. Y eso no es bien recibido en el sitio

Comment: @JuanSalvadorPortugal es correcto ahora?

Answer (score 3):

Puedes recorrer los elementos del enumerado con [`Enum.GetValues`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.getvalues?view=netframework-4.8):

```
foreach (int f in Enum.GetValues(typeof(EstadoVisita)))
    Console.WriteLine(f);
```

`Enum.GetValues` devuelve un Array, por lo que puedes filtrar los valores pares o impares mirando el índice:

```
public void RecorrerEstado(bool pares) 
{
    var valores = Enum.GetValues(typeof(EstadoVisita));
    for (int i = pares ? 0 : 1; i < valores.GetLength(0); i += 2)
        RealizarContexto(valores.GetValue(i));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Podrias ayudarte con el

[Enum.GetValues(Type) Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.getvalues?view=netframework-4.5)

quedando algo como esto

```
foreach (EstadoVisita item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(EstadoVisita))){
  if((int)item % 2 == 0){
     MetodoPar();
  } else{
     MetodoImpar();
  }
}
```

tambien se podria haber obtenido directamente el valor del enum usando

```
foreach(int item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(EstadoVisita))) { 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero sería añadir el parámetro para identificar si es par o impar, una vez hecho, puedes filtrar en `foreach` usando tanto `.GetValues` para conseguir los valores o `.GetNames` si lo que te interesa son los nombres.

Te dejo un ejemplo con ambos casos:

```
public void RecorrerEstado(int nPar)
{

    //Foreach para recoger los valores 
    foreach (EstadoVisita item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(EstadoVisita)))
    {

        if (nPar % 2 == 0 || nPar == 0)
        {
            // Blah blah par 

        }
        else
        {
            // Blah blah impar
        }
        nPar++;

    }

    //Foreach para conseguir los nombre
    foreach (string item in Enum.GetNames(typeof(EstadoVisita)))
    {
        if (nPar % 2 == 0 || nPar == 0)
        {
            // Blah blah par
        }
        else
        {
            // Blah blah impar
        }
        nPar++;
    }

}
```